# AllowAnonymous not Working MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using a custom filter (defined as follows):

```
        if (user == null || !user.Active)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                {"controller", "Home"},
                {"action", "NotAuthorized"}
            });
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
```

This is run site-wide (in `RegisterGlobalFilters()` within FilterConfig.cs. However, there is one page I'd like to allow access to - the NotAuthorized page. In the HomeController, I have created the following `ActionResult` method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult NotAuthorized()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Being unauthorized does lead the user to this view, but it results in a redirect loop (likely because the filter is still being run on this page).

How can I allow anonymous users to access this page?

Comment: `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute is designed to suppress the `[Authorize]` attribute, not your custom authorization filter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to check for the attribute in your custom filter.

Try:

```
if (!filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), false)
    && !filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), false)
    && (user == null || !user.Active))
{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check for the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` in your custom filter. Here is one, resuable way to do it.

Add the following extension method.

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool HasAttribute(this ActionExecutingContext context, Type attribute)
    {
        var actionDesc = context.ActionDescriptor;
        var controllerDesc = actionDesc.ControllerDescriptor;

        bool allowAnon = 
            actionDesc.IsDefined(attribute, true) ||
            controllerDesc.IsDefined(attribute, true);

        return allowAnon;
    }
}
```

Then use it in your filter.

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // use the extension method in your filter
        if (filterContext.HasAttribute(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute)))
        {
            // exit early...
            return;
        }

        // ...or do whatever else you need to do
        if (user == null || !user.Active)
        {
            filterContext.Result = 
                new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                { "controller", "Home" }, 
                { "action", "NotAuthorized" }
            });
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Here is [a fiddle that implements a solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/phsCr0).

Comment: It is important to also check if [AllowAnonymous] is applied on the method or the controller, I know SO hates "thanks" comments but - "thanks". Helped me out.